# Deleted anaconda to remove python3 in the hopes of going back to python2

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x

I installed python3 with anaconda when I did some of my ML stuff. Now I wanted to use python2 for a script I'm building but python defaults to python3 and I couldn't find any solution to switch or remove python3 so I deleted anaconda folder hoping python to revert back to python 2 since it won't be able to locate the python3 folder (inside anaconda). But instead I'm getting this

```
 -bash: //anaconda/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know how to get python2 working again? I'm fine with uninstalling python3 and I'm on Mac btw. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
python2 myscript.py
```

instead of

```
python myscript.py
```

Since python points to python3 in your case. If you want to uninstall python3: [refer this](https://superuser.com/questions/276840/uninstalling-python-3-on-a-mac)

Alternatively, you may change the python alias using:

```
alias python=/usr/local/bin/python<version>
```

Add it to `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.profile` for [few of the OS X versions](https://superuser.com/a/370042/578301)) if you want it to point to python2.x over 3 always on the shell.

Answer (score 0):

When you deleted your install, you didn't really change where your system is looking for Python. You could change your system's `PATH` variable so that it doesn't look in the `anaconda` folder, but I sometimes find environment variables wonky (I probably shouldn't). You could add a line like:

```
alias python="/path/to/your/python"
```

to your .bashrc file, but there are better ways!

Rather than deleting your install, I recommend running different [virtual environments](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/) for the different version of Python that you need. Basically run the following commands in your terminal to create an environment for Python 2.7 (leave off the `$` and anything before it; that just indicates the terminal prompt):

```
$ conda create -n py27 python=2.7 anaconda
$ source activate py27
[py27] $ python --version
```

which (for me) returns:

> Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

The last line verifies which version of Python you are running now. For Python 3.4 use the same, but name it `py34` (or whatever you like) and replace `python=2.7` with `python=3.4`.

When you want to use 2.7, use `source activate py27`, then start `python` or `ipython` or whatever. When you want to use 3.4, use `source activate py34` instead. When you are done with either, type `source deactivate`.

If you need to point a development environment (like PyDev for Eclipse) to your binaries you can find them under your anaconda folder; something like `/path/to/anaconda/envs/py27/` or `.../envs/py34/`.